# Locked question with many downvotes but good answers

Tags: discussion, specific-question, flagging

The question ["How to deal with instructor forcing me to do an uninteresting optional exercise?"](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/84437/how-to-deal-with-instructor-forcing-me-to-do-an-uninteresting-optional-exercise) has been locked recently. The question is kind a of mirrored question to [How to deal with uninterested students during an optional exercise session?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/84388/how-to-deal-with-uninterested-students-during-an-optional-exercise-session) and I think that both questions are a good and especially, both have great answers. However, the first question was has received several downvotes and also quite a few upvotes (currently being at -6 total). I imagine that the downvotes are partly due to the somehow offensive phrasing "some internet people".

My guess is that the question has been locked because of the heavy downvotes; [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22229) you find some reasons why posts should be locked (heavy downvotes are not exactly on the list…). As a locked question, there can't be up- and downvotes on the question and also no edits or comments can be made. I have the feeling, that the question should have been better received and would like to edit it (tone down a little), comment that I find the question reasonable and also upvote it. I could have flagged for moderator attention, but thought, I could learn more if I asked on meta.

Specifically:

- Is asking on meta equally good as flagging?
- Why was this question locked? (I have some guess, probably would have done the same, but I am curious.)
- How to proceed with the question?

Answer (score 4):

It says in the lock notice:

> This post has been locked due to the high amount of off-topic comments generated. For extended discussions, please use chat.

That question in particular was locked due to (now-deleted) comments that degenerated into schoolyard name-calling. (The downvotes may have been a reaction to those same comments.)

The lock will automatically expire in five days, and you can edit it then.

Comment: Ok, I was late to that post, so that I did not see these comments anymore (lucky me, I guess). Thanks for the explanation and the info.

Comment: "that degenerated into schoolyard name-calling": Sigh. Due to the different time-zone, I always miss the fun :-)

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Indeed. In particular, having seen the initial comments, I think your claim there that "This is a question which mirrors the other one, written from the point of view a student who is hypothetically in that position" is almost certainly not the case.

Answer (score 2):

It is locked for 5 days to let things cool down. Specifically the number of off topic comments.  After the timeout it will automatically unlock. At that point you will be able to edit it.